# Exporting OpenLayers.Layer.WMS to GeoJSON / KML

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, kml, geojson

I'm looking the way to exporting an especific region of a WMS layer to some XML format (GeoJSON, GML, KML) using OpenLayers and Geoserver. I've found how to export features objects with OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON.write(), but this method only allow converting feature objects or geometry objects.

An example of my idea: I'm viewing a map of a certain country with a couple of WMS layers with some data. Then I zoom to a particular state of that country and I want to export what I'm viewing to GeoJSON or KML for use that in a desktop GIS application (like QGIS).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Get the bounding box of the area that you are requesting

  layer.getExtent().toBBOX()
- Build a WFS request using the BBOX [here](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/178) a simple request. As output format choose json

Answer (score 0):

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392813/1665906) there is an interesting answer about getting a KML representation with WMS. The only problem that I've found is that Qgis has problems with a KML with multiple geometries.